# Is this fuse on a mains switch adequate?

Tags: mains, fuses

Given this diagram for a section of a mains circuit (seems like there's no varistor symbol) -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2finb6n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I gather that it's important for this fuse to be present if the MOV short-fails. The fuse "time current characteristic curve", which I assume indicates when the fuse *blows* given a certain current and time:

[image: fuse]

It seems the "rated" current is not the melt current, but rather the current that the system is expected to typically draw; and that the melt current is much higher, dependent on time applied.

Are the circuit values appropriate? Is this compatible with residential mains?

Edit: I had been considering a PPTC fuse, but that idea was somewhat dead-on-arrival. To accommodate an AC motor with a startup surge potentially above 4A, the PPTC options are very limited, bulky, slow-acting and expensive. In comparison, filament fuses seem cheap, abundant and fast-acting.

Comment: Not appropriate for a motor or cap load

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist OK... why not?

Comment: Eventually that MOV will die, and since MOVs typically fail short-circuit you'll be glad there's a fuse there.

Comment: @brhans What makes you say that the MOV will die? Is it not properly rated?

Comment: You must consider local voltage surge and nominal variances  and same TBD for load. So your choices are too tight.

Comment: AC motors surge 300% to 500% during startup

Comment: It's rated just fine for a 120V line, but the more voltage surges a MOV absorbs the shorter its life becomes ... eventually it will die.

Comment: Looking at the other PPTCs available, they're fairly limited in the range that would support a 5x current surge. Basically there's a 4A and a 7.5A. And they take over 20s to trip! So is there a different technology I should be investigating?

Comment: There may not be a resettable device that will protect a 120 watt motor. You probably don't need an MOV. The motor will probably not be damaged by anything an MOV will prevent. It would help to know more about the motor.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I don't know much about the motor, other than that it's a "typical" single-phase ceiling fan. Also, the MOV is less to protect the motor, and more to protect the relay contacts from arcing.

Comment: If a typical ceiling fan has any protection at all, it is likely to be a thermal fuse embedded in the winding. If you buy a relay that is rated for an AC motor load, it doesn't need any protection.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the fault current ratings of pptc fuses .Say if you have 240VAC and the circuit wiring and the fuse has a resistance of say 1 ohm .The pptc fuse must interupt a prospective fault current of a whopping 240 amps .Double check your ratings ,most small pptc fuses will shatter despite having a say 265VAC rating.